# Elastic Beanstalk not creating RDS Parameters

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following this tutorial in an effort to create a Django application on AWS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html

I was able to get everything working with a local sqlite database but I am trying to push the app to a production server. While going through the Elastic Beanstalk init process, I choose to create an RDS instance.

My mysite/settings.py looks like this:

import os

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
```

I should have access to RDS parameters at this point but I don't. The manage.py  file becomes unresponse.

```
(djangodev)laptop-id:mysite user-name$ python manage.py runserver
Unknown command: 'runserver'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

(djangodev)laptop-id:mysite use-name$ python manage.py
Usage: manage.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                        Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                        2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output
  --settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                        "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                        used.
  --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH
                        A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                        "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
  --traceback           Print traceback on exception
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 376, in execute
    sys.stdout.write(self.main_help_text() + '\n')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 242, in main_help_text
    for name, app in six.iteritems(get_commands()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/andrewcopp/Developer/mysite/mysite/settings.py", line 17, in <module>
   'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
  File "/tmp/djangodev/bin/../lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'RDS_DB_NAME'
```

Any idea as to what I might overlooked? Anything more information I can provide to make things clear

Comment: If I remember correctly, an `env` file should have been created with those variables set in them. Try `source ./env` and then retry your command.

Comment: remember to ignore your local_settings.py and local_settings.pyc

Answer (score 0):

You need a local fallback to a different database in settings.

In your **settings.py** file, replace the DATABASE variable with this:

```
DATABASES = {}

try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError, e:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
```

Now create a **local_settings.py** in the same directory as your settings.py and enter the following code:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db.djangodb',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ()
```

Now add your local_settings.py file to your **.gitignore** file.

Run `$ python manage.py syncdb` and now you can run the django server locally.

Most of this is copy pasta from this blog post I found:
http://grigory.ca/2012/09/getting-started-with-django-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually switched from using Django to Rails and didn't have the same problem in a Ruby environment. I'll try to go back at some point and validate your response so I can select your answer if it is correct.