# Script timed out before returning headers: wsgi.py

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk. It was working fine when we were using sqlite during development. Once we added RDS/PostgreSQL it started making the error in the title and the app is now totally unresponsive on EB.

I've followed [Script timed out before returning headers: wsgi.py on elastic beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477268/script-timed-out-before-returning-headers-wsgi-py-on-elastic-beanstalk) question and re-deployed many times with the same results.

I've done **eb ssh** and restarted the httpd service and got this error ([Elastic Beanstalk not creating RDS Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159079/elastic-beanstalk-not-creating-rds-parameters)).

I removed the **os.environ** references from **settings.py** and hardcoded the values from those I specified during **eb create** and from the data tier config page. This didn't help either as I was back to point zero again with the error in the title.

Here's the eb create command:

```
eb create --database --database-engine postgres -i t2.medium
```

What am I missing?